# Puzzle involving people, favourite monument and work department

Tags: logical-deduction

We have to determine who works in which department and who likes which monument.

[image]

> Seven people namely D, E, F, G, H, I and J like seven different monuments namely, Taj Mahal, Red Fort, Charminar, India Gate, Qutub Minar, Victoria Memorial and Sanchi Stupa.
>   Each of them work in either of the three fields viz. Economics, Management and Pharmacy with at least two of them in a field. (Note: None of the information given is necessarily in the same order.)
>
> The one who likes Qutub Minar works in field of Management only with G.
>   The one who likes Charminar works with the one who likes Sanchi Stupa.
>   J works with the one who like India Gate.
>   I neither works with G nor in the field of Pharmacy.
>   J does not like Charminar.
>   D likes Red Fort.
>   D does not work with J.
>   F work with only one person.
>   F does not like Qutub Minar.
>   H works with I.
>   I does not like Charminar.
>   Neither G nor F likes Taj Mahal.

(I'm leaving the image in case it contains information other than the text in it. dcfyj)

My findings:

1) I and h work in economics department.

2)F works in Pharmacy .

3)G is in management department and works along with the one who likes Qutub Minar.

After that I can't solve the puzzle.

Source: SBI PO exam 2016

Comment: Could you transcribe the image you posted? Would make life a lot easier for pretty much everyone.

Answer (score 2):

It's not you, it's the problem (at least as written). It's not well-enough defined. Here are two possible answers, both of which satisfy all conditions.

> ```
>  D    Pharmacy    Red Fort
>  E    Economics   Charminar
>  F    Pharmacy    Victoria Memorial
>  G    Management  India Gate
>  H    Economics   Sanchi Stupa
>  I    Economics   Taj Mahal
>  J    Management  Qutub Minar
> ```

OR

> ```
>  D    Economics   Red Fort
>  E    Management  Qutab Minar
>  F    Pharmacy    India Gate
>  G    Management  Victoria Memorial
>  H    Economics   Charminar
>  I    Economics   Sanchi Stupa
>  J    Pharmacy    Taj Mahal
> ```

There are more possible solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

The hints do not determine everything uniquely as the other answer shows.
But quite a bit is uniquely determined.

For easier reference, let me number the hints:

1. The one who likes Qutub Minar works in field of Management only with G.
2. The one who likes Charminar works with the one who likes Sanchi Stupa.
3. J works with the one who like India Gate.
4. I neither works with G nor in the field of Pharmacy.
5. J does not like Charminar.
6. D likes Red Fort.
7. D does not work with J.
8. F work with only one person.
9. F does not like Qutub Minar.
10. H works with I.
11. I does not like Charminar.
12. Neither G nor F likes Taj Mahal.

From the first hint:

> The field of G is Management.

Therefore the fourth and tenth hints give:

> The field of I is Economics, and so is that of H.

We can then figure out what F does:

> By hint 7 and the previous observation, F can't do Economics. By the first hint only two people work in Management: G and the one who likes Gutub Minar. By hint 9 F is neither. Thus F is in Pharmacy.

We then now the distribution of work:

> By hint 1 only to people work in Management, and by hint 8 (and the previous observation) only two work in Pharmacy. That leaves three people to Economics. Therefore D, E, and J are in three different fields.

We can restrict the possible monuments of G:

> Charminar and Sanchi Stupa need to have the same field, but the only one that works with G is in management and likes Qutub Minar (hint 1). Thus the monument of G cannot be any of these three. Red Fort is ruled out by hint 6, Taj Mahal by hint 12. Thus the monument of G is either India Gate or Victoria Memorial.

We can further restrict the field of D:

> It cannot be Management by hint 1.

And that of J:

> Suppose J is in Engineering. Then D is in Pharmacy and E is in Management. Thus E is the one who likes Qutub Minar. The monument of F cannot be Charminar or Sanchi Stupa (per hint 2 and the observation that G likes India Gate or Victoria Memorial), Qutub Minar (taken), Red Fort (taken), or Taj Mahal (hint 12). Thus F and G like India Gate and Victoria Memorial in some order. But neither of them is in engineering, the field of J, which contradicts hint 3. Thus J is not in Engineering.

The solution is not unique as the other answer shows, but if it was (as it should!), it could be used:

> People H and I are almost interchangeable. What we have figured out so far implies that hint 4 holds for H as well. The only asymmetry is hint 11. Therefore, if the solution is unique, one must not be able to swap I and H, and so H must like Charminar.